# Error in opening Chrome in Python Script using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a script in python using selenium, but I am stuck on opening a tab inside Chrome. When run, the script opens the Google Chrome main page, but that's all. It doesn't open the link I am trying to get to, nor prints anyhting, nor exit the page which should be done in the driver.quit() line and I just have to press CTRL+C in the terminal to manually shut it as it just runs infinitely .

I am relatively new to python and linux and I must get this done for a school project. I have no idea what is wrong, please help me solve this issue.
Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path="/usr/bin/google-chrome"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://pcgarage.ro/")
print (driver.title)

driver.quit()
```

P.S. : I tried the same code with Firefox as driver and it behaves just fine and as expected, but I couldn't find a way to solve the marionette issue (which is mandatory for my project) so I had to switch to Chrome as there are already a lot of examples on how to solve this type of issue. I wouldn't mind geting some adivce on this issue also.

Comment: `options = Options()` is missing when you initialize the driver. Try with `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options = Options()`. Check driver and browser versions as well (they need to match).

Comment: Yes it was a problem of mismatching, thank you